# How to manually recompile a C++ extension for PyTorch

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, pybind11

I have a C++ file called `TaskManager.cpp` which contains C++ code for a class which is made available to Python code with pybind11. Currently, I install the Python package with `pip install -e .` in the the directory where `setup.py` resides. The content of `setup.py` is given below:

```
from setuptools import setup
from torch.utils import cpp_extension

setup(name='TaskManager',
      ext_modules=[cpp_extension.CppExtension('TaskManager', ['src/TaskManager.cpp'])],
      cmdclass={'build_ext': cpp_extension.BuildExtension})
```

At the moment, I'm doing heavy development on `TaskManager.py`. `pip install -e .` takes a lot of time to execute and so I'm wondering: Is there a way to manually invoke *ninja* to compile the extension without having to call *pip* each time?